# Please Help Me With A PHP Form From A Theme - I need to change fields to spanish

Tags: php, forms

I hope you can help me out, I am using a Wordpress Theme. It comes with a page template of a form. You can see the form functioning at my url:

http://getpaidtotryitfree.com/contactenos/

This is a URL for a different project. I took it down so I could put my client´s website up. I cannot figure out how to change the fields to show up in spanish. Here is the code:

http://getpaidtotryitfree.com/wp-content/themes/13Floor/contact.txt

```
<input type="text" name="et_contact_name" value="<?php if ( isset($_POST['et_contact_name']) ) echo esc_attr($_POST['et_contact_name']); else esc_attr_e('Name','13floor'); ?>" id="et_contact_name" class="input" />
```

So I went through all the "values" and chanded the part in parenthesis to ('Nombre','13floor') and so on for all other values.

When I did that the field wouldn´t dissapear on click, like it does right now, so I thought "thats alright" i´ll just highlight it and fill it in but once I did that it activated the error "Please Fill In All Fields" so it didnt accept that. Ok...So then I did:

Press Control + F, to find all the places with "et_contact_name" and changed it to "et_contact_nombre", I started with:

```
<input type="text" name="et_contact_**nombre**" value="<?php if ( isset($_POST['et_contact_**nombre**']) ) echo esc_attr($_POST['et_contact_**nombre**']); else esc_attr_e('Nombre','13floor'); ?>" id="et_contact_**nombre**" class="input" />
```

Then with the Control + F command I found all others like:

```
$et_site_name = is_multisite() ? $current_site->site_name : get_bloginfo('name');
        wp_mail($et_email_to, sprintf( '[%s] ' . esc_html($_POST['et_contact_subject']), $et_site_name ), esc_html($_POST['et_contact_message']),'From: "'. esc_html($_POST['et_contact_**nombre**']) .'" <' . esc_html($_POST['et_contact_email']) . '>');
```

And did the same process with email,subject,message,etc. No luck though, the form didnt work then, it did change the fields, but it was not functional. (The highlighting deal I told you earlier)

I was able to change:

```
<input class="et_contact_submit" type="submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e('**Enviar**','13floor'); ?>" id="et_contact_submit" />
```

Which was "submit" this changed the text in the button, and left the form functional, I wish all other fields were as simple lol.

Ok and aside from this, there is no place in the .php where I can see how to change the error activations like:

```
Fill Name field
Fill Email Address field
Invalid email
Fill Subject field
Fill Captcha field
Fill Message field
```

I only see this piece of code:

```
$et_contact_error = true;
        } else if ( empty($_POST['et_contact_name']) || empty($_POST['et_contact_email']) || empty($_POST['et_contact_subject']) || empty($_POST['et_contact_message']) ){
            $et_error_message .= '<p>' . esc_html__('**Make sure you fill all fields**. ','13floor') . '</p>';
            $et_contact_error = true;
```

But "Make sure you fill all fields" never even comes up when using the actual form, so as you can see I am completely lost I hope you can help me out, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks for contacting us

Answer (score 0):

The default values for the fields are stored in

http://getpaidtotryitfree.com/wp-content/themes/13Floor/epanel/page_templates/js/et-ptemplates-frontend.js?ver=1.1

lines 67-70.

UPDATE

Yes, you should also translate the values in the form, you can find them at
`... else esc_attr_e('XXXXX','13floor'); ...`
and at
`... esc_textarea('Mensaje','13floor'); ...`

Example:

```
...
<input type="text" name="et_contact_name" value="<?php if ( isset($_POST['et_contact_name']) ) echo esc_attr($_POST['et_contact_name']); else esc_attr_e('Nombre','13floor'); ?>" id="et_contact_name" class="input" />
...
<input type="text" name="et_contact_email" value="<?php if ( isset($_POST['et_contact_email']) ) echo esc_attr($_POST['et_contact_email']); else esc_attr_e('Email','13floor'); ?>" id="et_contact_email" class="input" />
...
<input type="text" name="et_contact_subject" value="<?php if ( isset($_POST['et_contact_subject']) ) echo esc_attr($_POST['et_contact_subject']); else esc_attr_e('Sujetos','13floor'); ?>" id="et_contact_subject" class="input" />
...
<textarea class="input" id="et_contact_message" name="et_contact_message"><?php if ( isset($_POST['et_contact_message']) ) echo esc_textarea($_POST['et_contact_message']); else echo esc_textarea('Mensaje','13floor'); ?></textarea>
```

Comment: thank you, so do I also change the ones under form.php? because I changed the ones in the javascript but still no luck